# set different message base on each tab?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, devexpress

how can i show different message box depend on the tab control.
if i click on tab header of xtrapage1 `messagebox.show("page1")` and if i click on tab header of xtrapage2 `messagebox.how("page2")`
the code i use was in event mouse down

```
private void xtraTabControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   DevExpress.XtraTab.ViewInfo.XtraTabHitInfo hi = xtraTabControl1.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
   if (hi.HitTest == DevExpress.XtraTab.ViewInfo.XtraTabHitTest.PageHeader)
   {                                
       MessageBox.Show("a");
   }
}
```

it keeps showing `"a"`

[image: SCREEN SHOOT1]

Comment: Does it need to be in the MouseDown event? because it is easier to do in the SelectedPageChanged event and then do MessageBox.Show(e.Page.Name);

Comment: yes, must be mousedown. its for another purpose. like reload database sql select

Comment: Why? If you need to reload database sql before the page is displayed you can use the SelectedPageChanging event maybe?

Comment: well because there's a schedule not gridview or what ever. so iam just giving out a sample like above.. so can you solve it? because everytime i hit a tab header, it show `"a"`. what i want is when iclick on first tab header show `"a"` and when i click on second tab header show`"b"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void xtraTabControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DevExpress.XtraTab.ViewInfo.XtraTabHitInfo hi = xtraTabControl1.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
    if (hi.HitTest == DevExpress.XtraTab.ViewInfo.XtraTabHitTest.PageHeader)
    {                                
        MessageBox.Show(hi.Page.Text.ToString()) );

        if(hi.Page.Name == xtraTabPage1.Text.ToString()) 
            MessageBox.Show("a");
    }
}
```

Comment: @chopperfield When a post answers your question don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by click on check mark near the post. While you can accept only one answer, you can vote as many answer as you find useful, including the accepted one by click on up arrow near the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (YourTabControl.SelectedTab.Name == "tabName" )
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Or you can achieve the same functionality on selectedIndexChanged event of tab.

```
private void YourTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (YourTabControl.SelectedTab == YourTabControl.TabPages["YourTabName"])
     {
         // your matched condition.
     }
}
```

Comment: can you give me with mouse down event? because i need it for other purpose to refresh select database.. iam not looking for selectedindex change

Comment: yes, i have..
`if(xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage.Name == xtraTabPage1.Text.ToString())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("b");
                }`
doesnt work

Comment: xtraTabcontrol1 tabpages collection. i add tab from there